# Saving Kveik the old fashioned way?

Tags: yeast

I've been reading about Norwegian Farmhouse Ales and I'm quite curious about them. Should I drag a wooden wreath through the dregs of my Norwegian Farmhouse Ale and hang it up to dry and re-use it? Is this really viable?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Though this method is still used today by some breweries that want to stay true to the historical methods.

There's more reliable methods of preserving and pitching cultures using modern methods.

Comment: I guess what I am asking if it worked for hundreds of years, why do we need all these fancy methods for re-using yeast. I don't plan on doing this but does raise a question on if we pamper our yeast too much.

Comment: @farmersteve historically it was just something that worked, they didn't really know why. Results were an ever-changing but current culture of their local. Breweries today pitching with a wreath, do take care to store it in a controlled environment. But still it's just so they can say "look we do it the old way, isn't it cool?"